# reference a fixed column in mutate_at / mutate_all / mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr

Was trying to do a simple task: for all character columns in the dataset, if the column referenced is `"#NA#"` and the `age` column is above 14 I want to transform `"#NA#"` into `999`, so my dataframe looks like this:

```
age   var1     var2      num_var
20    "#NA#"  "hello"    35
30    "bye"  "#NA#"      32
10    "hi"  "#NA#"       35
```

And want to transform it into this:

```
age   var1     var2      num_var
20    999  "hello"     35
30    "bye"  999       32
10    "hi"   "#NA#"    35
```

(Could also be "999" instead of 999)

Tried something like this:

```
replace_NA <- function(x){
  if_else(x=="#NA#" & age>14, 999, x)}

df %>%  mutate_if(is.character, replace_NA))
```

But I'm getting a `object 'age' not found` error. What can be done in a case like this?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting (to me) is that if you use a purrr-style lambda function then using age directly is recognized: `df %>% mutate_if(is.character, ~ifelse(.x == "#NA#" & age > 14, 999, .x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the function to have 'age' as input argument.  In addition, change 'yes' to return a character element instead of numeric i.e.  `"999"` as `if_else` is type specific compared to `ifelse`

```
replace_NA <- function(x, age){
  if_else(x=="#NA#" & {{age}}>14, "999", x)
}
```

and test it as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character), replace_NA, age = age))
```

-output

```
   age var1  var2 num_var
1  20  999 hello      35
2  30  bye   999      32
3  10   hi  #NA#      35
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(20L, 30L, 10L), var1 = c("#NA#", "bye", 
"hi"), var2 = c("hello", "#NA#", "#NA#"), num_var = c(35L, 32L, 
35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun, worked like a charm! Still struggling with non-standard evaluation, but each one of these helps me understand a bit further